White Screen of Death on Wordpress Website
A white screen of death is displayed on my website. No matter which page you are on, it remains completely white. The Wordpress admin panel is not affected and is completely accessible.
My website runs on LAMP, so I use Ubuntu Server, PHP (Version: 8.3), Apache2, Mysl & Wordpress
The website was still working the day before without any problems and I haven't made any major changes to the website for a few days (no new plugin, theme, new code or anything else).
The only change I have made concerns Cloudflare. Since I have a second test website on a separate test web server and I can't run both via the standard Https port, I changed the test website to port 2053. For this I also created a worker in Cloudflare, which ensures that the traffic is forwarded to the correct IP with port (i.e.: 94.XXX.XXX.XXX:2053).
Only after this change did I visit my website again and then I noticed that it had the white screen of death.
Unfortunately, undoing all the changes in Cloudflare did not help.
I have also already tried this:

I have deactivated Cloudflare
Deactivated all plugins
Changed the theme (from New Twenty Four to Astra)
Activated Wordpress debug logs (unfortunately, no error message is displayed on the website)
Ubuntu restart and system update
.htaccess deleted and Wordpress Standard Config adopted
Mysql database manually read and checked for errors (nothing found)

WP Debug Log:

[12-Oct-2024 08:30:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  ltrim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /var/www/html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4482
[12-Oct-2024 08:33:06 UTC] Successfully loaded service schemas from server response. (fetch_service_schemas_from_connect_server)
[12-Oct-2024 08:33:10 UTC] WordPress database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction for query
INSERT INTO wp_actionscheduler_actions ( `hook`, `status`, `scheduled_date_gmt`, `scheduled_date_local`, `schedule`, `group_id`, `priority`, `args` )
SELECT 'wp_mail_smtp_queue_process', 'pending', '2024-10-12 08:33:10', '2024-10-12 08:33:10', 'O:32:\"ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule\":5:{s:22:\"\0*\0scheduled_timestamp\";i:1728721990;s:18:\"\0*\0first_timestamp\";i:1728721990;s:13:\"\0*\0recurrence\";i:60;s:49:\"\0ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule\0start_timestamp\";i:1728721990;s:53:\"\0ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule\0interval_in_seconds\";i:60;}', 5, 10, '[null]' FROM DUAL
WHERE (
SELECT action_id FROM wp_actionscheduler_actions
WHERE status IN ( 'pending', 'in-progress' )
AND hook = 'wp_mail_smtp_queue_process'
AND `group_id` = 5
 LIMIT 1 ) IS NULL made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WPMailSMTP\Core->get_tasks, WPMailSMTP\Tasks\Tasks->init,debug.log

Apache2 Error logs:
[Sat Oct 12 09:00:07.065118 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18030] AH00163: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 12 09:00:07.065154 2024] [core:notice] [pid 18030] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Oct 12 09:50:49.475939 2024] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 18030] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
[Sat Oct 12 09:53:56.967559 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18030] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sat Oct 12 09:53:57.048545 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19229] AH00163: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 12 09:53:57.048584 2024] [core:notice] [pid 19229] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Oct 12 09:55:08.352714 2024] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 19229] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
[Sat Oct 12 10:06:48.686732 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19229] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sat Oct 12 10:07:14.356756 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1185] AH00163: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 12 10:07:14.356872 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1185] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Unfortunately all without success. I don't know where the error is coming from, nor what else I can do.
Update:
Due to the great answer of a user I deactivated the plugin wp mail and tried to access the website via locolhost, which led to the same white screen. So Cloudflare is probably not the cause. Instead of Astra, I have now activated Twenty Twenty Three as a theme and have the following error messages when using wp-cli or the command “wp core verify-checksums”:
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-blog-header.php Warning: File doesn't exist: wp-config-sample.php Error: WordPress installation doesn't verify against checksums.

And this is what my wp-config.php looks like, so far it looks normal to me:
https://pastebin.com/6vevqBe3
Thanks for your help!

This issue that you are facing, can come from several reasons. You can try this:
1- download the same Wordpress version that you already have from official website, and replace it with your Wordpress website manually (DO NOT replace wp-content directory).
2- Let's put your correct data into your new wp-config.php file.
3- I face to this issue most of the time just because PHP version conflicts (most likely your plugins). Change your PHP version to another one.
4- You have a deadlock error for SMTP plugin. Run this command DELETE FROM wp_actionscheduler_actions WHERE hook = 'wp_mail_smtp_queue_process'; in your PhpMyAdmin.
5- If the issue still exist, you can check your apache (if you are using apache of course) config and everything related to workers for example: MaxRequestWorkers 256  # Adjust to a higher value based on server resources

Great news! You were right—the WordPress installation replacement did the trick. The website is working perfectly again! Thank you!!
